# Filter rows below a given row element within a group

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a set of dated events in each row linked to a location. Within each location I have an index event and a series of various matched events that may have happened before and/or after the index event. I need to subset all matched events that happened before the index event for each location. The data structure looks like this.

```
locid    match      date          score      iid
1        index      4/11/2013      15        1
1        matched    1/09/2013      23        2
1        matched    14/04/2013      1        3
1        matched    7/1/2014       21        4
2        index      2/4/2013       12        1
2        matched    1/2/2013       10        2
3        index      1/5/2013       23        1
3        matched    2/5/2013       10        2
4        index      3/3/2013        9        1
4        matched    10/2/2013      32        2
4        matched    1/10/2012      15        3
4        matched    4/3/2013       12        4
4        matched    10/3/2013      10        5
```

And I need to subset the dataframe so that I end up only with the rows with a date below the date of the index event for each location:

```
locid    match      date          score      iid
1        matched    1/09/2013      23        2
1        matched    14/04/2013      1        3
2        matched    1/2/2013       10        2
4        matched    10/2/2013      32        2
4        matched    1/10/2012      15        3
```

First time I ask here, so I'm hoping I'm not doing this the wrong way. I tried various permutations of solutions within R, but I'm struggling to find the right one.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a `data.table` possibility (assuming your data called `df`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, date := as.Date(date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")][, 
           .SD[date < date[match == "index"]], by = locid]
#    locid   match       date score iid
# 1:     1 matched 2013-09-01    23   2
# 2:     1 matched 2013-04-14     1   3
# 3:     2 matched 2013-02-01    10   2
# 4:     4 matched 2013-02-10    32   2
# 5:     4 matched 2012-10-01    15   3
```

---

Possible base R solution

```
df <- transform(df, date = as.Date(date, format = "%d/%m/%Y"))
do.call(rbind, by(df, df$locid, FUN = function(x) x[with(x, date < date[match == "index"]), ]))
#      locid   match       date score iid
# 1.2      1 matched 2013-09-01    23   2
# 1.3      1 matched 2013-04-14     1   3
# 2        2 matched 2013-02-01    10   2
# 4.10     4 matched 2013-02-10    32   2
# 4.11     4 matched 2012-10-01    15   3
```

---

And another possible base R solution

```
df <- transform(df, date = as.Date(date, format = "%d/%m/%Y"))
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$locid), function(x) x[with(x, date < date[match == "index"]), ]))
#      locid   match       date score iid
# 1.2      1 matched 2013-09-01    23   2
# 1.3      1 matched 2013-04-14     1   3
# 2        2 matched 2013-02-01    10   2
# 4.10     4 matched 2013-02-10    32   2
# 4.11     4 matched 2012-10-01    15   3
```

---

The basic idea here is to convert your `date` column to `Date` class so R will able to identify it's order. Afterwards, we basically split the data by `locid` and apply a filtering function on each chunk which selects only dates that comes before the `date` where `match == index`

Comment: Thanks very much. It is very helpful to see the different options. This reminds me I really need to get to grip with the data.table package.

Comment: You can do it without any package as I've illustrated in my last two options

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you could do it using dplyr:

```
require(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")) %>%
  group_by(locid) %>%
  filter(match == "matched" & date < date[match == "index"])

#Source: local data frame [5 x 5]
#Groups: locid
#
#  locid   match       date score iid
#1     1 matched 2013-09-01    23   2
#2     1 matched 2013-04-14     1   3
#3     2 matched 2013-02-01    10   2
#4     4 matched 2013-02-10    32   2
#5     4 matched 2012-10-01    15   3
```

Start by converting your dates to real `Date`-format, then group the data by column `locid` and then filter all those rows, where `matched == "matched"` and `date` is before the index date.

Note: Strictly speaking, you could remove the `match == "matched"` from the filter argument because you already filter for all those rows where date is `<` than the index date (hence, there couldn't be any rows with index), but I'll leave it there for now because I find it more easily readable and also in case you changed your condition for example to `<=` in which case it would be necessary to specify `match == "matched"` if you don't want index rows.

#### data:

```
df <- structure(list(locid = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), match = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("index", "matched"), class = "factor"), 
    date = structure(c(11L, 1L, 7L, 13L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 9L, 10L, 
    5L, 2L, 12L, 6L), .Label = c("1/09/2013", "1/10/2012", "1/2/2013", 
    "1/5/2013", "10/2/2013", "10/3/2013", "14/04/2013", "2/4/2013", 
    "2/5/2013", "3/3/2013", "4/11/2013", "4/3/2013", "7/1/2014"
    ), class = "factor"), score = c(15L, 23L, 1L, 21L, 12L, 10L, 
    23L, 10L, 9L, 32L, 15L, 12L, 10L), iid = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L)), .Names = c("locid", 
"match", "date", "score", "iid"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked a treat. I was trying to do something like this but doing an embarrassingly silly comment in the filter function.